# Is it good practice to have all classes to have inheritence

Tags: java

I was trying to draw a UML diagram for one of my older Java game projects. The game works but I realized that many classes didnt inherit. Since the game works, I know its not absolutely required to inherit classes for a program to work. I was just wondering if that might be a good idea or that it's a Java convention.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: There's no need to use inheritance if your code works without it. It's just one of many tools available.

Comment: ah ok, just another tool, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I was just wondering if that might be a good idea or that it's a Java convention.

It is not a good idea for a class to `extend` another class if the modelling doesn't suggest that it is necessary.  Certainly, there is no Java convention to that effect.

Use inheritance where it is needed.  If it is not needed, don't use it.

As noted, all Java classes<sup>1</sup> (and array types) have `java.lang.Object` as their ultimate superclass.  Your application's classes will all have a superclass, even if they don't explicitly `extend` one.

---

Is it harmful to `extend` when you don't need to?

I would argue that it is.

Assume (for that the sake of argument) that the `extend` is not warranted by either the modelling or the functional "needs" of the implementation of the model.

1. At best, an unnecessary `extends` is redundant.
2. The `extends` is misleading and time-wasting.  It may cause a future reader to spend time investigating the (assumed) meaning of the inheritance; i.e. why it is there, what it achieves.  Because Java programmers *assume* that inheritance relationships are there for a purpose.
3. In obscure cases, it could cause problems.  For example, a future maintainer might misunderstand the (lack of) purpose for the common superclass and start adding inappropriate functionality to it.  Of course, this primary blame for this is on the future developer, but he / she could point the finger at the existence of the common superclass as being a contributory factor.
4. There could be performance issues due to unnecessary method dispatching.  (This would be Java compiler dependent.)
5. There could be issues if you need to use (for example) an Object-Relational Mapping technology like Hibernate to map the classes to database tables.  Java inheritance complicates the problem of specifying the ORM mapping.  You don't want that complication if it is unnecessary.

---

<sup>1 - ... apart from `Object` itself.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

don't worry, all your classes inherit from java.lang.Object anyway